# Nano sized electric motors

Tags: motor, brushless-motor, motion

What is a good website for buying 1.5V continuous motors? I'm looking to build a clockwork robot but I cannot find a motor small enough to fit inside my power box and I don't want to mount it outside of the box. I have a 1" by .75" space that the motor needs to fit into. I have found a few websites but they look sketchy and none of them have good reviews.

Answer (score 1):

**Pager motors** will most likely do the trick. You can find some on [Robotshop](http://www.robotshop.com/en/solarbotics-tiny-pager-motor-tpm2.html) for example, with correct specs. This one is manufactured by [Solarbotics](https://solarbotics.com/).

[image]

Comment: It's torque will be reduced as compared to its nominal voltage, but yes it can still turn at 1.5V.

Answer (score 1):

Maxon motors are quality motors for industrial automation, their catalog is here - http://www.maxonmotor.com/maxon/view/catalog/

The 320173 fits in your dimensions ( assuming the 0.75" is diameter ) and is nominally 1.8V. New ones are around a hundred times more expensive than the cheap pager motors, but rated at 2W rather than 50mW.

You can get Maxon motors second hand on ebay (the ones I got were for N-gauge model locomotives- they were 12mm diameter x 19mm 12V 1.2W - the 118429 but with a easily removed gearbox on ebay as 139885 ), though you're probably better sizing the machine around the motor you can afford rather than trying to get a particular model.

Though I'm not sure why a clockwork robot needs an electric motor - surely it would be an electric robot!